# Problem with axis limits when plotting curve over histogram

Tags: r

newbie here. I have a script to create graphs that has a bit that goes something like this:

```
png(Test.png)
ht=hist(step[i],20)
curve(insert_function_here,add=TRUE)
```

I essentially want to plot a curve of a distribution over an histogram. My problem is that the axes limits are apparently set by the histogram instead of the curve, so that the curve sometimes gets out of the Y axis limits. I have played with par("usr"), to no avail. Is there any way to set the axis limits based on the maximum values of either the histogram or the curve (or, in the alternative, of the curve only)?? In case this changes anything, this needs to be done within a for loop where multiple such graphs are plotted and within a series of subplots (par("mfrow")).

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by other answers, this is what i ended up doing:

```
curve(insert_function_here)
boundsc=par("usr")
ht=hist(A[,1],20,plot=FALSE)
par(usr=c(boundsc[1:2],0,max(boundsc[4],max(ht$counts))))
plot(ht,add=TRUE)
```

It fixes the bounds based on the highest of either the curve or the histogram.

Answer (score 2):

You could determine the mx <- max(curve_vector, ht$counts) and set ylim=(0, mx), but I rather doubt the code looks like that since [] is not a proper parameter passing idiom and step is not an R plotting function, but rather a model selection function. So I am guessing this is code in Matlab or some other idiom. In R, try this:

```
set.seed(123)    
png("Test.png")
ht=hist(rpois(20,1), plot=FALSE, breaks=0:10-0.1)  
# better to offset to include discrete counts that would otherwise be at boundaries
 plot(round(ht$breaks),  dpois( round(ht$breaks),   # plot a Poisson density
         mean(ht$counts*round(ht$breaks[-length(ht$breaks)]))), 
         ylim=c(0, max(ht$density)+.1) , type="l")
 plot(ht, freq=FALSE, add=TRUE)   # plot the histogram
 dev.off()
```

Comment: This is in R, I just oversimplified the code when trying to extract the relevant bits.

Answer (score 1):

You could plot the curve first, then compute the histogram with plot=FALSE, and use the plot function on the histogram object with add=TRUE to add it to the plot.

Even better would be to calculate the the highest y-value of the curve (there may be shortcuts to do this depending on the nature of the curve) and the highest bar in the histogram and give this value to the ylim argument when plotting the histogram.